# Call to member function getClientRegistrationMode on a non object osticket

Tags: php, codeigniter, osticket

I am using codeigniter and trying to integrate Os-ticket into it. The reason for moving into codeigniter is for user login to work with Os-ticket log in.

Hence I created codeigniter library and was trying to load the 'view.php'  from library.

```
class Lib_support
{

protected $ci;

/**
 * __construct
 *
 * @return void
 * @author 
 **/
public function __construct()
{

    $this->ci =& get_instance();
    $this->ci->load->library('session');
    $this->ci->load->database();
    $this->ci->load->helper('date');
    $this->ci->load->helper('url');

    $CI=& get_instance();

    if (! isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }

}

    public function view()
    {

        require('support/view.php');
    } 

 }
```

That's where I got this message.

I placed the osticket files inside ../application/libraries/support/ folder.
And was calling `require('support/view.php');`

Can anyone let me know what went wrong here or what steps(config values) that I need to take care while changing/moving files to codeingiter library folder.

From what I understood, is that the INCLUDE_DIR failed and hence the require files might have failed to load. The code is working perfectly if I placed outside codeigniter folder.

Answer (score 0):

You are requiring a file form the `../application/libraries/support/` folder, For this I think you should use the `APPPATH` constant provided by CI.

```
require(APPPATH.'libraries/support/view.php');
```

Comment: Thanks... But the issue that I am talking about is from view.php(Which is Osticket file).  Ie         require('support/view.php'); is loading perfectly. But inside view.php osticket variables are not loaded. Anyone used Osticket inside Codeingiter???

Comment: What I've found is that you need to change the values in Bootstrap.php. define('INCLUDE_DIR',"/include/"); //Change this if include is moved outside the web path.
define('PEAR_DIR',INCLUDE_DIR.'pear/');
define('ROOT_DIR','');